# How to output 'null' in SQL?

Tags: sql, null

I'm curious about how to output 'null' in SQL. In many cases, we need to output 'null' if the targeted value doesn't exist. For example, for this leetcode problem: https://leetcode.com/articles/biggest-single-number/

The correct answer is

```
select ifnull((select num 
               from number 
               group by num 
               having count(num) = 1 
               order by num desc 
               limit 1), null) as num
```

The other way to write this code is

```
select ifnull(num, null) as num
from number 
group by num 
having count(num) = 1 
order by num desc 
limit 1
```

However, this code does not output 'null' if the targeted num doesn't exist. I don't understand why and am quite confused.I wonder if anyone can give a detailed explanation over this problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IFNULL() function returns the alt_value, if the expression is a NULL

The IFNULL() function returns the expression, if the expression is NOT NULL

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_ifnull.asp

the IFNULL works outside the main query because it is evaluating the result as a whole and not per record.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Do you mean ifnull can only evaluate the result as a whole instead of per record?

Comment: It can evaluate per row but if there is no result then there is nothing to evaluate... so to resolve use a parent query to evaluate the main query